# How to change outline button size?

Tags: dart, flutter

This is a silly question but I am new in Flutter. So I hope you guys can help me with this. Is there a way for me to change the size of the button in flutter?

Rectangular shape:

```
      OutlineButton(
        child: Text(forgot_password, style: TextStyle(color: colorWhite)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: colorWhite,
          style: BorderStyle.none,
          width: 0.8,
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
```

Circular shape:

```
      OutlineButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.google,
              color: colorWhite,
              size: 20.0,
            ),
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: colorWhite,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
              width: 1,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**You can use "ButtonTheme" to change size of buttons like below:**

> For Rectangular shape:

```
ButtonTheme(
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 100.0,
            child:   OutlineButton(
              child: Text('forgot_password', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.amber,
                style: BorderStyle.solid,
                width: 1.8,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
```

> For Circular shape:

```
ButtonTheme(
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 100.0,
          child: OutlineButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(
              Icons.screen_lock_portrait,
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              size: 40.0,
            ),
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.blue,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
              width: 1,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

**Also you can use Container as well SizedBox as below:**

> Container

```
Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 100.0,
          child: OutlineButton(
            child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.amber,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
              width: 1.8,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
```

> SizedBox

```
SizedBox(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 100.0,
          child: OutlineButton(
            child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.amber,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
              width: 1.8,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the ButtonTheme or a SizedBox like below

```
ButtonTheme(
  width: 100.0,
  height: 50.0,
  child: OutlineButton(
    child: Text('forgot_password', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.amber,
      style: BorderStyle.solid,
      width: 1.8,
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  )
)
```

```
Container(
  width: 100.0,
  height: 50.0,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3.0),
  child: SizedBox.expand(
    child: OutlineButton(
      child: Text('forgot_password', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.amber,
        style: BorderStyle.solid,
        width: 1.8,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` properties of your `Button`'s style property. This way you don't need to wrap the `Button` inside another `SizedBox`, `Container`, `ButtonTheme`, etc.

```
  OutlinedButton(
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(45),
    ),
    child: Text('Close'),
    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
  )
```

Here I set the minimum height to 45, which in most cases will be the exact height.

Of course you can do this in your app's theme, and make it effective for the whole app.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found working for me. I have used `fixedSize` property of `OutlinedButton.styleFrom`.

```
OutlinedButton.icon(
   style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
   fixedSize: Size(10, 40),
   alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-1.0, 0),
                      side: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Colors.black38,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid)),
             onPressed: () {},
             label: Text("Login with Facebook"),
             icon: Icon(Icons.facebook),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found working for me. I have used fixedSize property of ButtonStyle:

```
 OutlinedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
            Size(270, 300),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
          shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Size widget.

```
style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)
                ),
              minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(100)
            ),
```